Location and size of HDMI data island periods for very small resolutions
According to Wikipedia:

Each data island period is 32 pixels in size and contains a 32-bit packet header, which includes 8 bits of BCH ECC parity data for error correction and describes the contents of the packet. Each packet contains four subpackets, and each subpacket is 64 bits in size, including 8 bits of BCH ECC parity data, allowing for each packet to carry up to 224 bits of audio data.

Since each during data island period each 10-bits contain 4 bits of information and there are three channels, that means that 1-pixel worth of audio and auxiliary data contains 12 bits. Since from above it follows that shortest data period possible contains
$$32 + 64\cdot 4 = 288$$ bits of encoded data. That is at least 24 pixels worth.
Since the data island period must be transferred in the porch part of the frame and must be preceded by 8 times the preamble (adding another 8 pixels), the minimum space to transfer audio data must be 32 pixels.
Even with VGA resolution, we have horizontal front porch, sync, and back porch being 16, 96, 48 pixels long respectively. The front porch is not sufficiently large, and the as sync period must transfer control packets, only the back porch here can fit audio and auxiliary data.
HDMI does not work just for fixed resolutions, it works for all possible resolutions which can be allowed by its bandwidth. How can an even lower resolution, say 32×21, transfer audio and auxiliary data? I assume sync periods can be used to (partially) fit in the preamble since sync bits and bits signifying the following period are sent over different channels, but still, with a small enough frame even that may not be sufficient. Does HDMI simply not allow audio for the small resolutions, or am I wrong about the size and positioning of the data island period?

Two possible problems in your assumptions.
The sync period can carry data islands. The control period is needed only when the control signals change, and they do not change during sync periods. The sync signals are stable for 96 clocks.
And since this is HDMI you are talking about, you cannot transfer any arbitrarily small resolution. For instance the minimum pixel clock is 25 MHz. Or you can but you need to have enough room in the non-video parts for whatever you want to transmit.
Which is why e.g. interlaced SD video is transferred as pixel-doubled as 13.5 MHz is too low pixel clock as per the specification.

Well, to my understanding - sync regions ust always correlate to control data period as control packets have two bits dedicated for hsync and vsync. Why would they have dedicated bits if it's not meant to be used. Also, how would a receiver distinguish between porches and syncs otherwise? It is my understanding that syncs are used for receiver to wrap around pixel rows, and distinguish frame ends. And the control packets are distiguishable because they are a uniqe sbset of 10bit sequences. But now that you say that assumption is wrong I'm confused what even is the need  for sync periods.

And how does the receiver distinguishes pixel row ends, frame ends, etc. Also I was under impression you can achive very low resolutions like 16x16, for example by increasing framerate to maintain the minimum pixel clock frequency

@NikolaiSavulkin No the control periods are used to change the control signals, including HS and VS. HS and VS are stable during the active video line and during the blanking period except when the HS and VS change. And HS changes only twice during a line, and VS changes only twice during a frame. You need the control periods for changing control lines just like you need data periods for changing the data lines, and they cannot be changed simultaneously, it's either or. You misinterpret control periods for sync periods.

And you know pixels start when video island starts and pixels end when video island ends. You sure can send 16x16 video if you want but you still need the horizontal and vertical blanking periods that are long enough to send the metadata for each frame and e.g. audio.
